# Xamarin Android открыть новую активити с новой родительской активити

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Мне необходимо реализовать следующее поведение приложения:

1. Из root Activity пользователь переходит до Act 1.3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Из Act 1.3 открывается Act 2.2, чьей родительской активити является Act 2.1, а её - root Activity. При этом Act 1.1, Act 1.2 и Act 1.3 должны очиститься из стэка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. При нажатии кнопки "Back" должна открываться Act 2.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас для открытия Act 2.2 я использую такой код:

```
Intent act2_2 = new Intent(act1_3, typeof(Act2_2));
act2_2.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(act1_3);
stackBuilder.AddNextIntentWithParentStack(act2_2);
act1_3.StartActivity(act2_2);
```

Однако, после нажатия кнопки "Back" открывается Act 1.2

У rootActivity прописан атрибут:

```
[Activity(Label = "rootActivity", Name = "rootActivity")]
```

У Act 2.1:

```
[Activity(Label = "Act2.1", Name = "Act2_1", ParentActivity = typeof(rootActivity))]
[MetaData("android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY", Value = "rootActivity")]
```

У Act 2.2:

```
[Activity(Label = "Act2.2", Name = "Act2_2", ParentActivity = typeof(Act2_1))]
[MetaData("android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY", Value = "Act2_1")]
```

В чём может быть проблема? Возможно вы знаете, как сделать это на Java, подскажите, как, а я уже адаптирую под Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Код следующий:

```
Intent act2_2 = new Intent(act1_3, typeof(Act2_2));
Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(act1_3)
    .AddNextIntentWithParentStack(act2_2).StartActivities();
```